# php redirecting code http to https

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect my www.mysite.in to https://www.mysite.in, I tried all possible code of php in index.php as below mentioned but still unable to redirect....I am not getting exact solution. Please help me regarding.

```html
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != '') {
    header("location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
} else {
    header("location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
}?>
------------------------------------OR---------------------------------------
<?php

if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == ""){
    $redirect = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: $redirect");
}
?>
------------------------------------OR----------------------------------------
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "")
    {
        $HTTPURI = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); // Optional.
        header("Location: $HTTPURI"); 
        exit(0);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you able to modify/create a .htaccess file? If so try http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/force-ssl-htaccess.html

Comment: I have hosted my site on godaddy.com, I don't know how to create .htaccess file too...will you please help to guide about?.

Comment: You can create an .htaccess file by transferring a file to your server and renaming it; executing `touch filename` on the server; or by executing a number of commands in PHP to generate/create a file (file_put_contents, fwrite, etc.)

Comment: If you want to require *only* SSL connections (i.e. you don't want any users connecting via HTTP), you can always opt for [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/HTTP_strict_transport_security) headers. They aren't supported by a few older browsers or Internet Explorer currently, but the next version of IE is said to adopt it - so that's one way to add the redirect =]

Comment: I tried Vainglory07's code it work for me.... Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about like this:

Have a function that will check the protocol of the website:

```
function is_https() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) and $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) {
        return TRUE;
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) and $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Then if not, you do the redirect.

```
if (! is_https()) {
    header("location: https://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}");
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to do this via `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 3):

Better you can use .htaccess with the below code. Instead of putting manual php code in each page you can control one file the whole website.

```
# Switch rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# Do index.php to root redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is good idea. thumbs up. But i think the if he's using PHP framework, PHP approach to his problem doesn't need to call the script on every page. It can be called globally once on every request.

Comment: This is a bad idea for SEO purposes, this cause loop redirect in most cases